# How to branch in perforce

Tags: perforce, unreal-engine4

I'm a software engineer that uses git professionally but haven't tried using perforce until today. I searched about branch in perforce but I noticed that most of the informations that I found were all made by just using the branch in GUI then it creates a new folder (ie. /depot/MAIN/ to /depot/DEV/)

Is this how it works? What's the standards in naming the branches? Is it all caps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Branch names do not have to be in upper case only.
To create a new branch you can use the 'p4 integrate' command.

You can also use 'p4 copy' or 'p4 populate', depending on whether you want to exactly copy the source, or do the branch and submit in one action.

More information about branching is located here:
  https://www.perforce.com/perforce//manuals/p4guide/chapter.codelines.html

Comment: Your link is broken.  I got a 404.

Answer (score 0):

If you're used to git branches you might like Perforce streams and the `p4 switch` command, which works a lot like `git branch`.  For example:

```
p4 switch -c dev
```

stashes your current work, creates a new branch called `dev` based on your current branch, and switches to it.  To bring your current work into the new branch, add the `-r` flag.

At its core streams really use the same concepts as "classic" (unmanaged) inter-file branching, and there are things you can do with Perforce's branching model that you can't with git's, but if you want something that feels more or less like git the `switch` command abstracts away a lot of the commands you'd have to learn otherwise.